# Altitude problem IOS

Tags: ios, gps, mkmapview, altitude

I have a problem in getting the altitude , it returns 0.0000 . Here is my code:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
NSString *tAltitude  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [newLocation altitude]];
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord=newLocation.coordinate;
MKCoordinateSpan span = {.latitudeDelta =  0.005, .longitudeDelta =  0.005};
MKCoordinateRegion region = {coord, span};
[map setRegion:region];
NSLog(@"Location: %@", [newLocation description]);
NSLog(@"altitudine:%@",tAltitude); }
```

Comment: Are you running this on a simulator or a real device?

Comment: Real device.And the desired accuracy is set to kCLLocationAccuracyBest so i don't know what is the problem .

Comment: The problem is that i was inside.When i went out and tested it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are indoor, iPhone uses cell tower, or WIFI location. These location will not return altitude. You have to test outdoor to get GPS.

To make sure that you are using GPS, check the horizontal accuracy as well. If it is in the range of 2 digits, you should be on GPS, and most likely you will get altitude reading