# Getting Altitude(height from sea level) of my location in iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, gps, cllocation, altitude

I am trying to get Altitude of my location in my application. But every time I try `altitude` property of `CLLocation` object I am getting `0.00` as result.

I googled for my query and I got a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870480/ios-corelocation-altitude) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788328/altitude-problem-ios). This link is saying that if I access CLLocation with wifi or cell tower it will be null. Even if I try to set `desireAccuracy` to best than even it don't make sure that app will use GPS. It is also saying that if I am indoor that I won't be able to access GPS.

I many cases it its not sure that app will use GPS only. I want some way for getting Altitude from wifi or cell tower too. For that I googled more and I got [Google Earth API](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/ocean) but I think this is for Microsoft .net technology only.

Now according to this situation I think for a solution I can create a web service in Microsoft Technology and pass my location there and I can get altitude as response but I don't want to do this.

Can anyone suggest me how to get my location's altitude from ios. Is there any way available or not? If yes than please navigate me in right direction.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit1**

I used `CLLocationManager` for updating location and when I get my location I need altitude.

**Edit2**

According to @fishinear's answer I tried following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [manager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation];
    [manager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [manager setDelegate:self];
    [manager startUpdatingLocation];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    if ([newLocation verticalAccuracy] >= 0) {
        NSLog(@"Altitude = %lf",newLocation.altitude);
    }
    NSLog(@"Vertical Accuracy : %lf",newLocation.verticalAccuracy);
}
```

`verticalAccuracy` is always `-1`. It is not changing even after running the app to last 30 Mins. I am runnin ios 4.3.2 on my 3GS. I am indoor so I think it is not accessing GPS using this code even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Android - Get Altitude By Longitude and Latitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995998/android-get-altitude-by-longitude-and-latitude) there is an Android solution but it is easily adaptable to iOS.

The answer is to use the [USGS Elevation Query Web Service](http://gisdata.usgs.gov/)

From the top answer there, basically you just send an HTML Web request to:

```
http://gisdata.usgs.gov/xmlwebservices2/elevation_service.asmx/getElevation?X_Value=" + 
             String.valueOf(longitude)   + 
             "&Y_Value=" + String.valueOf(latitude)             
             + "&Elevation_Units=METERS&Source_Layer=-1&Elevation_Only=true";
```

Then you can parse out the response text from between the `<double>...</double>` tags

**Edit:**
It looks like you might be trying to get elevation outside the United States.

Google Maps API does provide an Elevation service and documentation at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/elevation

Comment: I tried using this URL and I passed x and y values `22.998851594142938` & `72.5317382812553173828125` respectively and the response is `<double>-1.79769313486231E+308</double>`. What I understand with this? How to get height with this?

Comment: thanks. your edited answer helped :) https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/elevation this is the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your original question:
GPS will always be used if you set desiredAccuracy to Best or BestForNavigation, and distanceFilter to kCLDistanceFilterNone when configuring the CLLocationManager. You will then also get altitude values in the CLLocation event.

However, it takes a short while before the GPS has "locked in" to enough satelites to be able to report the altitude. During that time it will report CLLocation events without altitude values. Therefore, you should ignore the first couple of events until the verticalAccuracy value is good enough for you. Also, check the timestamp, because sometimes the first CLLocation event is an old one.

Comment: But how can I make sure that which altitude value is correct among few values as you said??

Comment: Check the verticalAccuracy field in CLLocation. That indicates the accuracy of the altitude value, and is negative if the altitude was not determined.

Comment: Check my `edit2` in question. I implemented your suggestion but it didn't work.

Comment: Have you verified that Location Services are set to "on" for this app?

Comment: You state that you are indoors. When indoors, the GPS may have troubles "seeing" enough satellites to determine an altitude. Try it outdoors first, if it works there, then that is the cause.