# How to get elevation from current latitude and longitude using leafltejs OR mapbox javascript API

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am working with [leafletjs.com](http://leafletjs.com/) and added MAP. I want to get elevation from current latitude and longitude or current place only, but it will return whole path elevation.

```
var el = L.control.elevation();
el.addTo(map);
var gjl = L.geoJson(geojson,{
     onEachFeature: el.addData.bind(el)
}).addTo(map);
map.addLayer(service).fitBounds(bounds);
```

How can I find the elevation with either [mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/) or [leafletjs](http://leafletjs.com/).

Comment: What do you mean with current place only and current latitude and longitude? Looking at your code it seems that you are adding elevation to every feature element

Comment: elevation of current place only, above code return elevation of whole json data.

Comment: I want like this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/elevation-simple

Answer (score 4):

Leaflet is a map display library, not a data API, not a elevation raster query library.

For this, you will have to rely in some kind of elevation dataset (which one is "better" depends on your definition of "better").

For example, see [Getting Altitude(height from sea level) of my location in iphone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630664/getting-altitudeheight-from-sea-level-of-my-location-in-iphone-sdk/10630813#10630813)

Whether to use a service like that or whether you should have your own elevation dataset is up to you. In any case, Leaflet does not provide a favourite elevation query service by default (contrary to what Google Maps does, as it relies on Google's elevation datasets).

Answer (score 1):

Extending on @IvanSanchez's answer, you'll need to integrate a service to grab the elevation from your point. One such library which will do this with Mapbox is https://github.com/mcwhittemore/mapbox-elevation