# Getting the Altitude in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive, leaflet.draw

I was wondering if there is a way to get the altitude for my current location in leaflet like getting the latitude and longitude

```
this.marker = leaflet.marker([e.latitude, e.longitude]).addTo(this.map);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get elevation from current latitude and longitude using leafltejs OR mapbox javascript API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47649487/how-to-get-elevation-from-current-latitude-and-longitude-using-leafltejs-or-mapb)